# How to add -race argument in launch.json file?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, race-condition

I debug Go programs in Visual Studio Code. How can I add the `-race` argument in launch.json file?

I add config in launch.json like below, but it doesn't work.

```
"args": ["-race"]
```

Comment: Will your Go launch configuration take a "runtimeArgs" key?

Comment: Yes, I did like `"runtimeArgs": ["-race"]`. but it doesn't work @Mark

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `buildFlags` works.

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "auto",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": [
        ...
    ],
    "buildFlags": [
        "-race"
    ]
}
```